# Sending email after Windows Backup runs in Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup

I currently own a Windows Server Foundation (that does not support email sending) but wish to send a report email after running Windows Server Backup.

Do you know of any programs/alternatives to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing EventSentry Light and configuring it to send and email, with a Gmail account, on a specific event ID.

It's not as pretty as an email sent with the backup report, but it does the trick, at least I won't forget the backup exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to run Cygwin on the server and then run one of the free MTAs on that, such as Exim, or Postfix, or even Sendmail (or SSMTP)?

It's dirty as hell, but might just work.

Comment: Way dirty and much of a hassle, the EventSentry+Gmail was enough for me. Thanks for the answer though :)